# prove using $\epsilon-\delta$ method that $\lim \limits _{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{e^y\sin x}{x}=1$

Tags: calculus

I have $\frac{|e^y\sin x-x|}{|x|}\leq\frac{|e^y-x|}{|x|}\leq\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{x^2}}$

I am unable to proceed and find $\delta$

Comment: what is your $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition for a limit of a multi variable function??

Answer (score 2):

Hint: using
$$ \bigg|\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg|\le1$$
one has
$$ \bigg|\frac{e^y\sin x}{x}-1\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{(e^y-1)\sin x+\sin x-x}{x}\bigg|\le|e^y-1|+\bigg|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\bigg|.$$
Then using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739135/lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-sinxx-using-epsilon-delta-definition?rq=1) for
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$ 
one will get $\delta$ for $\epsilon>0$.