# Proving that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove the following assertion:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, we have to show that:

$$\exists \delta > 0 : 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |\frac{\sin(x)}{x} - 1| < \epsilon$$

Let us consider the following:

$$\cos(x) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1$$

if $0 < |x| < \frac{\pi}{2}$. So, we have:

$$0 < 1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1 - \cos(x) = 2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) \leq 2 |\sin(\frac{x}{2})| \leq |x| < \delta$$

That's, of course, assuming that $0 < |x| < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $\epsilon \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then let $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. This would ensure that $1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is still greater than 0.

If $\epsilon < \frac{\pi}{2}$, then let $\delta = \epsilon$. This would still mean that $0 < |x| < \delta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ so the inequality above would still be satisfied.

This proves the given assertion.

Could someone check my proof above and see if it works or not?

Comment: Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/329473/721644

Comment: If you solve the inequality, then $\delta$ works. (:

Comment: Eyy nice, thanks for the link, I'll check out the discussion there as well.

Comment: If you accept the "squeeze theorem," then letting $x\to 0$ in $$\cos(x)\le \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le 1$$suffices.

Comment: Can't accept that cos it hasn't been brought up in my text at this point, so I have to prove this in a more elementary way. Just to be sure, is there anything in my proof that could be improved upon?

Comment: What is the definition of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ you use?

Comment: The definition we're allowed to use is a geometric one based on the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove an inequality using some geometry :

Let $ \theta \in\mathbb{R} \cdot $ Observe the following figure :

[image]

Denoting $ \mathscr{A} $ the red region, (The triangle $ OBC $), $ \mathscr{B} $ the green one, (A part from the unit disc that has a circumference of $ \theta $), $ \mathscr{C} $ the ble one, (The triangle $ OCD $). $ \mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{A}} $, $ \mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{B}} $ and $ \mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{C}} $ are their respective areas.

We have : \begin{aligned} \mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{A}}\leq\mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{B}}\leq\mathscr{S}_{\mathscr{C}}\ \ \ \ \ \\ \iff \frac{\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{2}\leq\frac{\theta}{2}\leq\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}\ \ \ \\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cos{\theta}\leq\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta}\leq\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}\end{aligned}

Meaning, we have $ \lim\limits_{\theta\to 0}{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta}}=1 \cdot $

Comment: Thank you for the proof but I'm not quite allowed to use the squeeze theorem, which is what you utilized. We haven't proved that yet in the text I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

First change the name of the variable to $\theta,$ so we have to prove $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1.$$ Take a point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle in the first quadrant. The proof is almost the the same for a point in the 4-th quadrant. Then $\theta$ is the arc length from $(x,y)$ to (1,0) and $\sin \theta=y.$ We need bounds on the arc length. For a non-negative integer $n$ divide the interval $[x,1]$ into $2^n$ equal sub-inervals. Note that we deliberately include the case $n=0$ when the interval is left in one piece. For each division point $x_i$ on the X-axis let $P_i=(x_i,y_i), 0 \le i \le 2^n$ be the corresponding point on the unit circle so that $P_0=(x,y)$ and $P_{2^n}=(1,0).$ For $n \ge 0$ let $$S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}\text {straight-line lengths from $P_{j-1}$ to $P_j$}.$$ The triangle inequality shows that $S_0,S_1, ...$ is an increasing sequence and that $$S_n \le 1-x+y$$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n$ exists. We define the arc length=$\theta=\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n$Then $$\sqrt{(1-x)^2+y^2}=S_0 \le \theta \le 1-x+y$$. $$\sqrt{(1-\sqrt(1-y^2))^2+y^2}\le \theta \le 1-\sqrt(1-y^2)+y$$ The conditions $\theta \to 0$ and $y \to 0$ are equivalent. All that is needed now is to take the reciprocals in our upper and lower bounds for $\theta$, multiply through by $\sin \theta$, which is the same as $y$ to obtain upper and lower bounds on $\frac {\sin \theta}{\theta}$ in terms of $y.$ With the squeeze law for limits and a little algebra, you can finish the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the argument. I can't use the squeeze law to prove this because it hasn't yet been proven in my text. This will be excellent reference for when I do learn it.